Why does Haskell function tails include the whole list?
Introduction and context
In Haskell we have the function tail that provides the suffix of a list.
For example:
tail [1,2,3]
gives
[2, 3]
The function tails would give instead all the suffixes:
tails [1,2,3]
gives
[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]
Question
Why does it return tha whole list as first argument? I expected to return all real suffixes, i.e. I expected
tails [1,2,3]
to give
[[2,3],[3],[]]
or maybe even
[[2,3],[3]]
without the empty list.
Is there a formal/logical reason for tails to behave this way, or is it just random, i.e. simply how it used to work in the original implementation and never changed?
I searched the question around and I did not find a decent explanation for this.

It returns all suffixes = “real suffixes“ ≠ strict suffixes.

What do you propose to return for the empty list?

One could argue either way. Why shouldn't the whole list be included? It's easy to compute the "excluding" variant of tails form the "including" one, and vice versa, so it's not a huge deal. Still, any set is a subset of itself, so it makes sense to be inclusive on lists as well. Also, it's nice to be able to split the list at all points as [ .. | (y:ys) <- tails xs ]. By the way, would you also argue about excluding the empty tail?

@Chi I find this part of your comment very meaningful: "any set is a subset of itself"

@n.m.couldbeanAI tails [] = [] seems like a perfectly cromulent choice if one were to go this direction.

@DanielWagner you would then have a law of every list having an empty suffix, except for the empty list, which suddenly seems non-obvious and arbitrary.

As the documentation on tails :: [a] -> [[a]] [Hackage] says:

The tails function returns all final segments of the argument, longest first.

so all suffixes. A list is always a suffix of itself. tails is essentially implemented as:
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
tails [] = [[]]
tails xs@(_:xs') = xs : tails xs'

it thus returns the list itself, and the tails of its tail, if any. If you are only interested in the strict tails, we can work with the tail of the tale:
tail . tails

which is guaranteed to work, since for an empty list, tails [] will return a singleton list, and thus (tail . tails) [] will then return an empty list.

inits and tails were added in the Haskell 98 report, under the “List” section of the library report. I’m having trouble finding good citations since they don’t seem to have been mentioned on the mailing list archives. However, I believe there were a few original motivations.
I’ll refer to the current versions of inits and tails as inits0 and tails0; and define tails1 = drop 1 . tails0 (omitting the full suffix) and inits1 = drop 1 . inits0 (omitting the empty prefix).
The question is whether inits should be inits0 or inits1, and likewise for tails.

We should prefer more general functions whenever possible. However, in this case each can be expressed in terms of the other, so neither is more general.

zipWith (++) (inits list) (tails list) should produce copies of the original list. That means either (inits, tails) = (inits0, tails0) or (inits, tails) = (inits1, tails1), but not a mix of the two.

The inits of all of the tails should produce all of the contiguous segments of an input list, e.g. (inits <=< tails) [1, 2, 3] = [[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[],[2],[2,3],[],[3],[]] (including [] once for each tail segment). That isn’t true for (inits1, tails1).

In addition, the results of both inits and tails should be non-empty, to support use with partial functions like maximum that aren’t defined on empty lists, since this was before Data.List.NonEmpty became standard. Again, (inits1, tails1) doesn’t satisfy this, e.g. tails0 [] == [[]] but tails1 [] == [].


So it looks like we should choose (inits, tails) = (inits0, tails0).
This is also consistent with other list functions, for instance map sum . inits = scanl' (+) 0 for computing a prefix sum.
The naming is a bit unfortunate, since init and tail always drop one element but inits & tails don’t. Perhaps takes and drops would’ve been better.

"including [] once for each tail segment" - that seems arbitrary. I like the other arguments though!

@Bergi: Yeah, that part isn’t a goal, just a note about the example. Well, it’s true that there are only 1 + length list offsets in a list from which you can take a 0-length slice, but I’m not sure when that would be useful.

I think the natural analog of your drop 1 . tails (i.e. only strict suffixes, possibly including the empty suffix) is not drop 1 . inits, but rather reverse . drop 1 . reverse . inits (i.e. only strict prefixes, possibly including the empty prefix) (or, well, the better defined but not snippet-length version of that which doesn't reverse twice, something like liftA2 (zipWith const) inits (drop 1 .  inits)).
